# Adding event listeners and passing in the object

Tags: javascript, events, javascript-objects, dom-events

This is my current code:

Index.html

```
    AddEventListener('click', 'a[data-requestpartial]', function (obj, e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Error is happening here. this is undefined. obj is undefined.
        var url = this.getAttribute('href');
        LoadSection('#container', url, null, function (result)
        {
            window.history.pushState("", "", url);
        });
    });
```

On Script.JS

```
function AddEventListener(eventType, query, func)
{
    var objects = Select(query);
    for (var i = 0, len = objects.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        objects[i].addEventListener(eventType, function (e) { func(objects[i], e) });
    }
}
```

Basically, I am trying to add a "click" event listeners to ALL 'a[data-requestpartial]'. I would like to prevent the anchor default action, and then I would like to do the specific action I've requested.

How can I accomplish this? I've tried both "this" and "obj", however, both of them comes back as undefined.

Edit:

```
function Select(query)
{
    return query[0] === '#' ? document.getElementById(query.substring(1)) : document.querySelectorAll(query);
}
```

Here is a JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/q3Lse37y/2/

Comment: What is `Select` method ? Do share a fiddle or executable demo...

Comment: Sorry about that, updated to show the method. Basically, in this case, it's calling document.querySelectorAll.

Comment: Hi Rayon, I appreciate the help in posting this as a duplicate and providing the correct link, I can't seem to find the answer I am looking for though. I'm pretty new to java script. I feel like the thread you've posted is talking about inner/outer scope. I'm just trying to add both "event" and the "object" to my function.

Comment: Do share a fiddle to play with...

Comment: Sure, I'll write one up right now.

Comment: Wrote one up. Not sure if this is what you were looking for. It should prevent the <a> href link, and then it should get the URL and call the LoadSection() function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/q3Lse37y/3/

Comment: Or https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/q3Lse37y/4/

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. Would you like to add it as a answer or anything? I can select it as the correct answer.

Comment: I may add it as answer but only if you need any explanation about what is happening..